# MySql converting row to column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a `MySQL` query which provides the following result,
[image]

The query used is

```
SELECT  modi, aid FROM (SELECT 
 GROUP_CONCAT(id) his,
an_id aid, 
GROUP_CONCAT(m_id) modi
FROM 
ah 
GROUP BY an_id, m_id) t1
GROUP BY aid, modi
order by aid;
```

Now I need a MySQL`query which will give me a result set where if column`aid`has the same value in two rows should create a new column with same`aid`and`modi`.

For example, the first two rows in the image as same `aid` but different `modi`. The result I need should have 3 column and the row should look like,

```
aid           modi                  modi2
27     6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,6              8
```

I am very new to SQL. Thanks in advance

Comment: MySQL is not the same as Oracle.. Besides the how to ask (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines requires you provide reproducible data a image isn't reproducible data

Answer (score 1):

Well, one method is:

```
SELECT aid, min(modi) as modi1, max(modi) as modi2
FROM (SELECT an_id as aid, 
             GROUP_CONCAT(m_id) as modi
      FROM annotation_history ah
      GROUP BY an_id
    ) t1
GROUP BY aid
HAVING min(modi) <> max(modi);
```